# SUMIF function on spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula, sumifs

I keep getting errors when writing this function. I have multiple tabs, and I'm trying to reference data on the INVENTORY tab.

I have attached a screenshot of the DATA.

Here is the formula that I wrote:

```
=Sumif(INVENTORY!Y2:Y248,"<=>",INVENTORY!X2:X248,"CASH",INVENTORY!L2:L248)
```

My goal is that when Y has a date *and* when X has the word "CASH" in it, then I need to sum the value in column L.

Any ideas?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUMIFS(INVENTORY!L2:L248, INVENTORY!Y2:Y248, ">0", INVENTORY!X2:X248, "CASH")
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's changed from the original formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(L2:L248,X2:X248,"CASH",Y2:Y248,">01/01/1900")
```

You cannot use multiple criteria in a SUMIF. Instead use SUMIFS which does allow this. EG: SUMIFS('range to sum','criteria1 range','criteria1','criteria2 range','criteria2',etc...)

Comment: A word of explanation would greatly help future visitors to understand this solution